# grape-swagger undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, ruby-grape

I'm using `grape` to build my restful API, but when I try to integrate it with Swagger via `grape-swagger` gem, it throws

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

when I visit `http://localhost:3000/swagger_doc` url

Here is my gem versions:

- rails (4.2.4)
- grape (0.8.0)
- grape-swagger (0.20.0)

And here is my directory structure & files:

`api/
api/base.rb
api/graduates.rb`

```
// base.rb
module API
    class Base < Grape::API
        mount API::Graduates
        add_swagger_documentation
    end
end

// graduates.rb
module API
    class Graduates < Grape::API
        resource :graduates do
            desc 'wow'
            get :all do
                Graduate.all
            end
        end
    end
end
```

In my routes file, I am just mounting the grape api base.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount API::Base, at: "/"
end
```

A detail for debug purposes: when I delete `resource` block from `graduates.rb`, swagger_doc url seems fine(but of course, without resources).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who encounter this issue, here is the answer:

As compatibility table says, `grape (0.8.0)` and `grape-swagger (0.20.0)` are not compatible with each other. This is solved when I use `grape (0.16.2)`.